# Compare values when keys is in common between 2 dicts

Tags: python

I don't understand why my code is not working when I try to compare 2 values for each key in common:

```
dict1 = {'test A': 'abc,bcd,edf', 'test b': 'bcd,edf', 'test c': 'pok,pub'}
dict2 = {'test A': 'abc,bcd', 'test b': 'edf'}

def diff_dict(self, dict1, dict2):
    return {x: dict2[x] - dict1[x] for x in dict1 if x in dict2}
```

Error:

```
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'str' and 'dict'
```

Output expected :

```
out = {'test A' : 'edf', 'test B': 'bcd'}
```

Comment: What is `dict1` and `dict2`? Show the data to make it reproducible.

Comment: In `dict2` value stored by key `x` is string when `dict1` contains dictionary.

Comment: @schwobaseggl I just edited

Comment: I get the error `TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'str' and 'str'`, not the one you posted. And the error is because you're essentially doing `'abc,bcd,edf' - 'abc,bcd'` for the first key, for example. Which version of Python are you on? Are there extra brackets somewhere which you removed?

Comment: In the future, boil your problem down to the actual issue. You could have just asked, "how do I compare `'abc,bcd,edf' - 'abc,bcd'` to produce `'edf'`. No need for the dict comprehension, etc.

Comment: You've also neglected to include: (a) does the order matter? (b) does number of occurrences matter? And so on

Comment: @BradSolomon oh ok I didn't knew if we could do that without dict comprehension

Comment: @BradSolomon (a) No the order doesn't matter, (b) yes the number of occurences matter

Comment: And will the values of `dict1` always contain _equal or greater_ number of elements than `dict2`? Or, would you possibly have `'abc,bcd' - 'abc,bcd,edf'`.  In other words, are you looking for a difference or a [symmetric difference](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#set)?

Comment: @BradSolomon yes dict 1 always, difference only

Answer (score 0):

This will not work because subtraction is not defined for dictionaries nor strings. It is, however, defined for sets. So one solution would be to convert the strings into sets, find the difference, and then convert it back to a list:

```
def diff_dict(dict1, dict2):
    return {x: ",".join(list(set(dict1[x].split(",")) - set(dict2[x].split(",")))) for x in dict1 if x in dict2}
```

It is not clear exactly what you are trying to do. If instead you are trying to find the [symmetric difference](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symmetric_difference) of the values represented by the same key, then you should use `^` instead of `-`.

Comment: thanks for your feedback. The actually problem is split is not working with dict... when I try this code I got `AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'split'`

Comment: Did you give us dict1 and dict2 exactly as you have them?

Answer (score -1):

The `-` operand in line `return {x: dict2[x] - dict1[x] for x in dict1 if x in dict2}` is trying to subtract two strings